# Online Quilt Pattern Design Contest

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle

Six contestants have each submitted a 3x5-square black and white design in the Key Foundation's 1st Annual Online Quilt Pattern Design Contest.

Below is the submissions list from their web page.

## [image]
Key Foundation

## Quilt Pattern Design Contest Submissions

| Dan | Dan N. |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

| R.O. | Ron |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

| Ron X. | Rox |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

---

Text translation for those who cannot view images:

```
***  
*_*  
_*_  
_**  
_*_
```

Key Foundation
Quilt Pattern Design Contest Submissions

Dan:

```
*_*  
*_*  
_*_  
__*  
___
```

Dan N.:

```
___  
**_  
*_*  
**_  
*_*
```

R.O.:

```
***  
*_*  
_*_  
***  
***
```

Ron:

```
___  
___  
*_*  
*__  
___
```

Ron X.:

```
***  
**_  
_*_  
*_*  
_*_
```

Rox:

```
___  
__*  
*_*  
**_  
*_*
```

[End text translation]

---

**How did each of these contestants place? (1st to 6th)**

The accepted answer will explain all logical steps. Diagrams are preferred.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Placements:

> 1. Ron
>  2. R.O.
>  3. Dan N.
>  4. Dan
>  5. Ron X
>  6. Rox

Entry:

> Every name is an anagram of a logic gate:
>  AND (Dan)
>  NAND (Dan N)
>  OR (R.O.)
>  NOR (Ron)
>  XOR (Rox)
>  XNOR (Ron x)

So

> Given the base key grid, figure out which 3x5 pattern could result in the contestant's entry when applying the corresponding logic gate. The easiest are XOR and XNOR because they are reversible.
> [image]

For the rest

> Think about which cells have to be black and which have to be white (marked orange), and fill in the rest (marked gray) to make a valid digit.
> [image]

Comment: (Great answer!) Curious what software you used to design the quilts. Did you code it?

Comment: @BeKind Excel :)

Comment: Ah, didn't even think of that!